# No module named 'django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_static'

Tags: django, django-models

my django version is 3.0.5 and django-suit version is 0.2.28 but why does this error happen?
the whole error information is as follows:

```
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\suit\admin.py", line 8, in <module>
    from suit.widgets import NumberInput, SuitSplitDateTimeWidget
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\suit\widgets.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_static import static
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_static'
```

Comment: Looks like you use an old version: the latest commit imports `static` over `admin_static`: https://github.com/darklow/django-suit

Comment: So does it mean that just upgrading django-suit will solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem.
Modify this file： \Python38\Lib\site-packages\suit\widgets.py

```
# from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_static import static
from django.contrib.admin import static
```

then rerun your program, maybe met problem below:

```
  File "D:\Work_Station\Python38\lib\site-packages\suit\templatetags\suit_menu.py", line 17, in <module>
    string_types = basestring,
NameError: name 'basestring' is not defined
```

modify the file : Python38\lib\site-packages\suit\templatetags\suit_menu.py

```
# from django.utils.six import string_types
from six import string_types
```

Comment: Just a note that you should fork the suit project rather than update site-packages.